# Set Default Value on SalesOrderForm in Microsoft Dynamics using COC

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics, default-value, x++

I have added field in salesTable and on the salesTable form. I want to put the default values like created when the sales order is created and Updated when sales order is updated. All I have to do is using chain of command.

Comment: What's your question and what have you tried so far? Take a look at [ask] for some help on how to ask questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new class,extension of SalesTable, with something like this:

```
[ExtensionOf(tablestr(SalesTable))]
final class SalesTable_MyExt_Extension
{
    void initValue(SalesType _salesType)
    {
        next initValue();
        
        this.myField = "foo";
    }

    public void update()
    {
        this.myField = "bar";
    
        next update();
    }
        
}
```